# How can I create new df3 from df1 where values are conditional on values in df2?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two DFs, DF1 and DF2. Each with dim (978350,50). DF1 is a matrix of values I measured, DF2 is a matrix of the errors of those values. I want to create a DF3, where all the values of DF1 are preserved if their error, stored in DF2, is <0.4. I also have lots of NAs in my DF1 & DF2 that I want to stay as NAs in DF3.

I tried doing this:

```
for (i in 1:978530){
  for (j in 1:50){
  if (DF2[i,j]<0.41&!is.na(DF2[i,j])){DF3[i,j]<-DF1[i,j]
    } else {DF3[i,j]<-9999}}}
```

but it takes so many hours to compute because of my huge dimensions. I set my NA value to 9999 because typing actual NA threw errors. I'm hoping there's a more computationally efficient / elegant way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
# copy the data
DF3 <- DF1
# change unsatisfied data with NA
DF3[is.na(DF2) | DF2 >= 0.4] <- NA # or you want it to be 9999
```

Comment: wow that worked perfectly and ran in less than 60 seconds... vs the multiple hours my code takes... thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, please also consider picking it as the answer.

Comment: Oops! Didn't know you could do that. Just picked it as the answer. Thanks again!